# Parse JSON files using c#

Tags: c#, json, parsing, csv

I've written a c# application that reads JSON files line by line and write csv files from it. I've create Model files for each csv format, objects for those model gets instantiated while parsing and are then written to csv at the end.

For Ex: if input file name is abc.json, create and instantiate object for abc, store it in data structure like List  and then write it to csv at the end.

**JSON file**:

```
{
  "Computer ID": "1697343078",
  "Application Name": "Reporting Services Service",
  "Date": "8\/25\/2015",
  "Count": "1"
}
```

My code to parse is as follows:

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(sFile, Encoding.UTF8))
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
    if (line.Contains("Computer ID") && counter == 4)
            {
              string[] tokens = line.Split(':');
              if (tokens.Length >= 2)
              {
                  resourceID = reg.Replace(tokens[1], "");
              }
              counter = counter - 1;
              line = sr.ReadLine();
          }
}
```

The parsing fails because of inconsistent format of data or other fields in input file. Code throws exception and parsing of that particular file fails completely. I want my code to reject the record for which parsing and continue parsing other records in the file and to finally generate a csv for it.

I want it to behave as below, 
Read the file line by line
If any error occurs while parsing, don't instantiate that object and continue parsing other lines for that file
Write the object to csv

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a small example of JSON with an error, and the corresponding CSV output you would like.

Comment: Also, explain what the error is (is it an exception, is it something else...?) and show your code that is related to the error...

Comment: Do this in the question post and not in the comment area. ;)

Comment: @Anky, please add your additional information to the question. Do not put it here in the comments. It is hard to follow and understand your problem if you spread the information about the problem "everywhere" ;-)

Comment: I added the JSON file there. @Anky you can use the code-formatting to add your CSV, error message and code.

Comment: why don't you use a real json parser?

Comment: @Anky, add details about the exception: (1) What is the type of the exception, (2) what is the exception message, (3) what is the stack trace of the exception (i.e., which line causes the exception) and (4) what is the variable `reg` you are using there (a regular expression perhaps...)?. Also, why are you not using JSON.NET or some other Json package out there...?

Comment: For example http://www.newtonsoft.com/json offers a really good JSON Reader/Writer.

Comment: Thanks for you comments. But I thought reading the files line by line could speed up the process and help me to manipulate the values as I want while reading. Can you please share any sample code to parse JSON files using JSON.NET parser and to tackle the scenario of continue csv generation even if error is encountered.

Comment: Also is there a way to introduce try catch block in the existing code such that whenever exception occurs file parsing any file, reject that line and continue parsing other lines

Comment: @elgonzo Error occurs when the value for date field in JSON file is null and format exception is thrown when null enters the below line date = Convert.ToDateTime(date).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");

Comment: @Anky, the code you have posted in your question is not related to the error. I am not sure why you would show us the the code parsing the Json line with "Computer ID", when the error is about the "Date" line. Whatever there is going on with the "Date"-related code i don't know (since you did not show the code parsing the date). However, take a look at the format string for converting your date: `"MM-dd-yyyy"`, and in your Json data, look at the date which is `"8\/25\/2015"` -- do you spot the differences (there are two...)?

Comment: I posted the same JSON file in which a date field is present. The value of date field is not consistent. Sometime, it's in correct date format while sometime it contains two \/ or a string like "No date found, so no data returned". Code fails at those inconsistent date values. Although I format the string to remove any unwanted characters before converting it into date time, but is there a way to check that correct string is inserted into Convert.To Date Time function  ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to parse you JSON data.  To do this, you need to:

1. Define classes corresponding to your JSON objects.
2. Where a `DateTime` property appears, declare it as a [nullable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx).  In the event a string like "No date found, so no data returned" is encountered, a null value can thus be stored in the property.
3. Create your own [`DateTimeConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_DateTimeConverterBase.htm) that, when parsing a nullable `DateTime`, tries the various date time formats that you might encounter.  If an invalid format is encountered, return `null` rather than throwing an exception.
4. Apply it to your `DateTime` properties using [`JsonConverterAttribute`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute.htm).

Thus, given the following converter:

```
public class DateTimeConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(DateTime?);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;

        var token = JToken.Load(reader);

        // For various JSON date formats, see
        // http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm

        // Try in JavaScript constructor format: new Date(1234656000000)
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Constructor)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = token.ToObject<DateTime?>(JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = new JsonConverter[] { new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter() } }));
                if (result != null)
                    return result;
            }
            catch (JsonException)
            {
            }
        }

        // Try ISO format: "2009-02-15T00:00:00Z"
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.String)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = token.ToObject<DateTime?>(JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(new JsonSerializerSettings { DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat }));
                if (result != null)
                    return result;
            }
            catch (JsonException)
            {
            }
        }

        // Try Microsoft format: "\/Date(1234656000000)\/"
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.String)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = token.ToObject<DateTime?>(JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(new JsonSerializerSettings { DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat }));
                if (result != null)
                    return result;
            }
            catch (JsonException)
            {
            }
        }

        if (token.Type == JTokenType.String)
        {
            // Add other custom cases as required.
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

You would apply it to your class as follows:

```
public class ComputerData
{
    [JsonProperty("Computer ID")]
    public string ComputerID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Application Name")]
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(DateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Example [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Hhh5XS).

Answer (score -1):

You did do not need a JSON parser. All you need is try catch block to ignore the exception during parsing the data in the line where data format is incorrect. By checking conditions, you should be able to handle that.

Here might be a solution, I did something like this before, but I then wrote a JSON parser my self at the end....

Entity class

```
 public class Info {
     public string ComputerID {get;set;}
     public string ApplicationName {get;set;}
     ...
 }
```

For parsing the text and ignore the errors when you parse the line

```
 Info record = null;
 var recordSet = new List<Info>();
 using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(sFile, Encoding.UTF8))
 {
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
         if (record==null){
                record = new Info();
                recordSet.Add(record)
         }
         try {
         } catch ( Exception e) {
          //You either log the data or ignore the exception here
         }
         //Check your property here, replace with your actual implementation here
         if (record.ComputerID!=null && record.ApplicationName!=null) {
               record = null;
         }

    }
 }
```

With things getting complicated, you might still need a parser to handle that, but that really depends on your needs.

Comment: This is bad advice.  When parsing JSON data, you really should use a JSON parser if possible.  Trying to take a shortcut with Regex or Split is a good way to introduce subtle bugs into your program.

Comment: @BrianRogers OK. Parser win. But I have to say, when anky is asking for a way to  _Read the file line by line If any error occurs while parsing, don't instantiate that object and continue parsing other lines for that file Write the object to csv_, you just telling hime using a JSON parser will do the trick. And did the parser do?

Comment: Fair enough, you're answering the question exactly as asked.  But I really think his whole approach is wrong.  He is saying that he has formatting inconsistencies in his data and is looking for a way to handle them.  It is much easier to do this using a parser.  See @dbc's answer for a better approach.

Comment: @BrianRogers I don't the see the answer reduce the room for bugs. To write a stable program, you could NOT just rely on a third library.